# How can I cluster 5 dimensional data using HDBSCAN

Tags: hdbscan

I am trying to cluster NTU-RGB+D 120 skeleton dataset using HDBSCAN. The numpy array of the skeleton data has 5 dimention

```
**dataset.shape=[40091, 3, 300, 25, 2]**
```

where No of data  = 40091, Coordinates = 3 (x-y-z), No of frame = 300, No of joints = 25, No of body in the video = 2

When I am trying to cluster it using hdbscan but the fit raises an error message saying it only accepts 2D data. How can I do it with 5 dimension. I am completely new to work with skeleton data and clustering.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the shape of the data using view() so that now it contains
samples * (frames*joints) to reduce the dimension